# Write my own iPhone app to read from credit card swipe reader

Tags: iphone, credit-card

I'm looking for a way to write my own app that can support credit card payment but using the credit card readers such as Blue Bamboo P25-M or MagTek iDynamo.

I'm pretty sure there's a way to do this, but I don't know what to do.

Do you think I need to contact those companies who make the reader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both devices appear to be "Made for iPod" and "Works with iPhone" - but there will a protocol name for which they are registered and an actual communications protocol that they will use for talking with iDevice. While you could probably discover the protocol name from one of the apps already written for these devices, reverse engineering the comms protocol would be daunting.

So, yes, I think that you would do best to contact these companies.

Answer (score 2):

Magtek allows you to do so though their documentation is the worst I've ever seen(read as nonexistent).

Answer (score 0):

Both of your examples use the Dock Connector, which means in theory you could write your own app to interface them - but only if the company in question wants you to. Apple provides hardware manufacturers with [an interface](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ExternalAccessoryPT/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009502) for external accessories, but the manufacturer must declare support and provide documentation for it. The manufacturer must provide you with documentation and details on how exactly the device works, which they may not want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try out Unimag. It comes with full documentation and SDK and also a sample project. You can easily integrate that in your application.

Comment: My unimag came without SDK. Is there a web to download it? Also, do you know about any demo app I could try with our cards (30 days demo or whatever) ?